# React-Native Keyboard not closing problem on Android. How can ı fix this

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard

React-Native Android On the add program page, when I first click on typing and then the clock, the keyboard does not close.

[image]

```
        <CustomInput3
              maxLength={50}
              value={content}
              onChangeTextUpperCase={text => setContent(text)}
              placeholder="Adı"
            />
```

how can ı fix this?

Comment: When do you want to close the keyboard? please give more clarification

Comment: When I click on the other input from one input, it gets buggy. It stays on the screen. I want to close when I click from one input to another

Comment: Is there any method which will call on click other input?

Comment: <CustomInput3
                datePicker
                datePickerType="time"
                placeholder="Başlangıç"
                viewStyle={{ width: responsiveWidth(151) }}
                //minDate={new Date()}
                onDateSubmit={date => {
                  setStartDate(date);
                  setEndDate(new Date(date?.getTime() + 15 * 60000))
                }}
                date={startDate}
              />
other input